# Spotify API Downloading ALL songs locally

Tags: api, spotify

We are looking to develop a web application which would allow users to play songs via Spotify API by tweeting in their song choices.

Since the internet connection can not be relied upon, in order to do this, we are hoping to cache ALL the track information locally and only connecting when songs need playing.

Now, how feasible would this be if we were to do this via the API or can we somehow have a single data dump?

Comment: libspotify creates its own cache when you use it, but just out of curiosity, exactly how is this supposed to work, the users, must they have a Spotify account? Because this sounds slightly illegal...

Answer (score 0):

> we are hoping to cache ALL the track information locally

This isn't really possible, since 1) there's no API to get everything in the Spotify catalogue, 2) that is a LOT of metadata - it'd be impractical to download and store it all locally, and 3) doing so would be against the Spotify API ToS anyway.

> and only connecting when songs need playing

If you need to connect to the internet to play anyway, performing the API call to get track metadata shouldn't pose a problem.